# python, libsvn and cant file python imports

Tags: python, libsvm

I have installed libsvm-3.12 and placed into:

- /home/ubuntu/libsvm-3.12

In my pythonpath I have the following:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/ubuntu/libsvm-3.12/python:/home/ubuntu/libsvm-3.12:$PYTHONPATH
```

This is in both .bashrc in home and in /etc/enviroments

I rebooted the machine.

From python I get:

```
>>> import svmulti
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named svmulti
```

How do I let python know where the lib is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given installation via `make` in `.../libsvm-3.12/python,`I think you also want:

```
>>> import svmutil
```

not:

```
>>> import svmulti
```

Comment: One of my more dumb moments:)

Comment: I'm usually lucky to spell 'import' correctly - thanks for upvote - woulda just made it a comment but it seemed a bit clearer to clarify the typo on multiple lines.